# Delete duplicate rows having minimum column value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to delete the results generated from the below query. Please help.

```
(select min([Last_Updated Date]),Ticket from Hosting_Open
where Ticket in 
            (select Ticket from Hosting_Open
            group by Ticket
            having count(ticket)>1 )
group by Ticket)
```

The above query gets the minimum update value for those ticket which have more than one value in another column.

Comment: Add sample data and expected OutPut

Comment: You want to delete rows from both table or from one only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like that:

```
Delete Hosting_Open
From Hosting_Open
Left Outer Join (
   Select Min([Last_Updated Date]) as [Last_Updated Date], Ticket 
   From Hosting_Open
   Group By Ticket
) As RowsToKeep On
   Hosting_Open.Ticket = RowsToKeep.Ticket And
   Hosting_Open.[Last_Updated Date] = RowsToKeep.[Last_Updated Date]
Where
   RowsToKeep.[Last_Updated Date] Is Null
```